# How to update a database value with an imagebutton in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, imagebutton

I am working on an php file, winch shows an table with values of the database. every row has an imagebutton at the end, which should change the status, displayed with an image.
so I think short function of it all must be, on click go to script go to php or jQuery?
the buttons also have to give the id of the user to the next script or function, or os there a better way?

here is my basic approach, with no functionality, for the moment

in index.php

```
include("function.php");

while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_user)) {
            
    $sqle = mysql_query("
                    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
                       places2user                                 
                    WHERE
                       user = '".mysql_real_escape_string($row_user['ID'])."'
             
                    ");
            $res23 = mysql_fetch_array($sqle);

echo <table>
  echo <tr>
    echo "<td>".$row_user['ID']." </td><td><input type=\"image\" src=\"images/".htmlentities($row_user['receive'], ENT_QUOTES)."\" id=\"status\" name=\"status\" ></td>
  echo </tr>
echo </table>
}
```

there is also a function.php, with a changestatus($id) function, which updates the database values, but I think, this is not the right way to code this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While programming, don't rely on javascript only. I always create form using just html and css, make sure it works, and than add fancy stuff with jQuery or so. This way you know the form will also work without javascript (great for users without it).

But to come to your question:

if you use this, it should do what you want:

```
<?php echo "<form action='?' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>".$row_user['ID']." </td>
<td><input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$row_user['ID']."'/>
   <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/".htmlentities($row_user['receive'], ENT_QUOTES)."\" id=\"status\" name=\"status\" ></td>
  </tr>
</table></form>";
```

Comment: oh ok, that would be a nice solution for me, because i only at beginner status in js an jquery. so this would be perfect for me. i try this way and let you know. thx for the fast answer!

Comment: the solution is a good and simple one. only the form shouldn't start at the beginning. there must be a form in every table-row, because with one form, you only get the last id of the table.

`<tr><form action='?' method='post'><td>...</td></form></tr>`

thanks for the help!